# Matching rows and keeping Greater-than-Equal-to values

Tags: r

I'm trying to match my rows by the maximum values of `Bird_count`, where if other rows relative to `distance` in the same `Year` is Greater-than or Equal-to the row with maximum `Bird_count` then keep it. Otherwise, remove all other rows below the maximum. So, the row with Bird_count as `maximum`, the Distance is then the **minimum** threshold for that **Year**.

Expected output from data:

```
# Groups:   Year [25]
   Distance  Year Bird_count
      <dbl> <dbl>      <int>
 1      2.8  1980         30
 2      2.2  1981        139
 3      5.1  1981          4
 4      2.4  1982         94
 5      2.9  1982         33
 6      4.8  1983          9
 7      2.3  1984         50
 8      3.8  1985        162
 9      6.4  1986          1
10      6.9  1986          1
11      3.2  1987        151
12      1.7  1988        150
 .       .    .           .
```

I have tried:

```
sliced_bird_data <- bird_data %>% slice_max(n)
bird_data %>% inner_join(sliced_bird_data, by=c("Year", "n"))
```

Reproducible code:

```
Bird_data <- structure(list(Distance = c(2.8, 1, 2.2, 5.1, 2.4, 2.9, 4.8, 
0.7, 4.6, 2.3, 4.8, 3.8, 6.4, 6.9, 4.2, 3.2, 0.7, 1.7, 3.9, 2.6, 
4.9, 0.2, 5.2, 3.9, 4.4, 3.6, 2.4, 5.7, 5.4, 0.3, 3.4, 5.6, 1.4, 
3.8, 2.1, 1.3, 3.9, 4.6, 4.6, 3.5, 1.4, 2.2, 2.7, 1.7, 2.8, 1.9, 
1.4, 0.8, 2.7, 1.3), Year = c(1980, 1980, 1981, 1981, 1982, 1982, 
1983, 1983, 1984, 1984, 1985, 1985, 1986, 1986, 1987, 1987, 1988, 
1988, 1989, 1989, 1990, 1990, 1991, 1991, 1992, 1992, 1993, 1993, 
1994, 1994, 1995, 1995, 1996, 1996, 1997, 1997, 1998, 1998, 1999, 
1999, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2003, 2003, 2004, 2004
), Bird_count = c(30L, 1L, 139L, 4L, 94L, 33L, 9L, 1L, 19L, 50L, 
25L, 162L, 1L, 1L, 53L, 151L, 23L, 150L, 86L, 273L, 14L, 31L, 
1L, 105L, 40L, 277L, 1099L, 2L, 8L, 3L, 634L, 6L, 240L, 147L, 
541L, 533L, 126L, 27L, 22L, 250L, 240L, 723L, 762L, 440L, 457L, 
478L, 192L, 42L, 946L, 228L)), row.names = c(NA, -50L), groups = structure(list(
    Year = c(1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 
    1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 
    1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004), .rows = structure(list(
        1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8, 9:10, 11:12, 13:14, 15:16, 17:18, 
        19:20, 21:22, 23:24, 25:26, 27:28, 29:30, 31:32, 33:34, 
        35:36, 37:38, 39:40, 41:42, 43:44, 45:46, 47:48, 49:50), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 25L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Do you mean `Bird_data %>% group_by(Year) %>% filter(Bird_count == max(Bird_count))` ?

Comment: @RonakShah I've noticed that for 1980, it doesn't pick the row with maximum bird_counts.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to `group_by` `Year`, updated the comment above.

Comment: @RonakShah When I try it on my larger dataset, it only takes `unique` maximum values, even though there are rows with Distance greater than the threshold. Mind if I edit the reproducible example code, and provide a different segment of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how it would be done with `data.table`. I'm sure a tidyversion could easily be done too

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Bird_data)

Bird_data[, .SD[Distance >= Distance[which.max(Bird_count)]], Year]

#>     Distance Year Bird_count
#>  1:      2.8 1980         30
#>  2:      2.2 1981        139
#>  3:      2.2 1981          4
#>  4:      2.4 1982         94
#>  5:      2.4 1982         33
#>  6:      4.8 1983          9
#>  7:      2.3 1984         19
#>  8:      2.3 1984         50
#>  9:      3.8 1985         25
#> 10:      3.8 1985        162
#> 11:      6.4 1986          1
```

It's basically the same using tibbles directly:

```
Bird_data %>% 
  group_by(Year) %>% 
  filter(Distance >= Distance[which.max(Bird_count)])
```